# Build custom Metric for Loss Function with Keras, with errors

Tags: customization, keras, conv-neural-network, metrics, loss-function

I'm trying to write custom metric function to set in the compile step wrote in this way:

```
self.model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=[self.dice_similarity_coefficient_metric,self.positive_predictive_value_metric,self.sensitivity_metric])
```

I wrote Dice Similarity Coefficient, Positive Predictive Value and Similarity in this way:

- FP = false positive
- TP = true positive
- FN = false negative

---

```
 def dice_similarity_coefficient_metric(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = np.array(K.eval(y_true))
        y_pred = np.array(K.eval(y_pred))
        FP = np.sum(y_pred & np.logical_not(y_true)).astype(float)
        TP = np.sum(y_true & y_pred).astype(float)
        FN = np.sum(np.logical_not(y_pred) & 
        np.logical_not(y_true)).astype(float)
        return K.variable(np.array((2 * TP) / (FP + (2 * TP) + FN + 
        K.epsilon())))
```

---

```
    def positive_predictive_value_metric(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = np.array(K.eval(y_true))
        y_pred = np.array(K.eval(y_pred))
        FP = np.sum(y_pred & np.logical_not(y_true)).astype(float)
        TP = np.sum(y_true & y_pred).astype(float)
        return K.variable(np.array(TP / (FP + TP + K.epsilon())))
```

---

```
    def sensitivity_metric(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = np.array(K.eval(y_true))
        y_pred = np.array(K.eval(y_pred))
        TP = np.sum(y_true & y_pred).astype(float)
        FN = np.sum(np.logical_not(y_pred) & 
        np.logical_not(y_true)).astype(float)
        return K.variable(np.array(TP / (TP + FN + K.epsilon())))
```

when i run the code i have the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_3_target' with dtype float
>        [[Node: dense_3_target = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Can someone care to explain where is the problem?
Where i'm wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it's better to define metrics using backend functions. For example:

```
def false_negatives(Y_true, Y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.round(K.clip(Y_true - Y_pred, 0, 1)))
```

It can be checked on an example data with 5 FN:

```
y_true = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]], dtype=np.float32)
y_pred = np.array([[0.3, 0.99, 0.99, 0.1], [0.6, 0.99, 0.99, 0.1], [0.1, 0.99, 0.99, 0.1]], dtype=np.float32)
n_fn = np.sum((y_true - y_pred) > 0.5)
Y_true = K.placeholder((None, 4), dtype=K.floatx())
Y_pred = K.placeholder((None, 4), dtype=K.floatx())
n_fn = false_negatives(Y_true, Y_pred).eval(inputs_to_values={Y_true: y_true, Y_pred: y_pred})
```

HTH